# How to assign textbox value to gridview in asp textbox is a seperate object not a part of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to assign textbox value to gridview in asp textbox is a seperate object not a part of gridview. on button click event all text box values assign to grid view as neew row.
i am wondering about how to do that i search a lot but can't find correct way to do that.
![enter image description here][1]

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("ADD") == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("id", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("UnitPrice", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Price", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            dr["Id"] = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Text;//item id
            dr["Name"] = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[1].Text;//item name
            dr["UnitPrice"] = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[2].Text;//iten unit price
            dr["Price"] = "mkj";
            dr["Quantity"] = "mkj";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
```

please see this img
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkhZe.png

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Gridview.Rows[1].Cells[0].Text = TextBox1.Text;
```